# push an array element if certain element not exists or update in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have to update an array inside a document on the basis of a string which i get from the `req.value`.

My collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "key": [
      "1-value-1",
      "1-value-2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "key": [
      "2-value-1",
      "2-value-2"
    ]
  }
]
```

I have another string `newString`.
Let's assume two conditions:

- when `req.value` is in the array in that case replace the array value with `newString`.
- else `rew.value` is not present simple push the `newString` in the array.

Eg: I have a `newString = 1-value-3` and `req.value = 1-value-2` in that case replace array value `1-value-2 to 1-value-3`.
Else if `req.value` isn't in array push `newString` value to array.

This is the [collection](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E3EMA5YVGWH) on which i want to perform operations on.

Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: Please copy the input data directly into this question instead of linking to mongoplayground; it makes it easier for both new readers and answerers.   Second: you write `update to 1-value-3 if 1-value-2 exists else push 1-value-3 if 1-value-4 doesn't exist`   That is unclear.   Please edit the question to show exactly what the desired output shape should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update with pipeline**

Query

- if `1-value-2 exists` change to `1-value-3`
- else `push 1-value-3 in the end of the array (i think you want this)
- filter to check if it exists
- if exists map to update
- else concat to add in the end of the array

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6259bbabf7e3c64c6511e191)(update,exists)
[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6259bbcef7e3c64c6511e192)(push(concat), missing)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},
[{"$set": 
   {"v2-exists": 
     {"$ne": 
       [{"$filter": 
           {"input": "$key", "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this", "1-value-2"]}}},
         []]}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"key": 
     {"$cond": 
       ["$v2-exists",
         {"$map": 
           {"input": "$key",
            "in": 
             {"$cond": 
               [{"$eq": ["$$this", "1-value-2"]}, "1-value-3", "$$this"]}}},
         {"$concatArrays": ["$key", ["1-value-3"]]}]}}},
 {"$unset": ["v2-exists"]}])
```

---

**Update operators**

Query1(check if exists)

```js
find({"_id": {"$eq": 1}, "key": {"$elemMatch": {"$eq": "1-value-2"}}})
```

If query1 empty result send this(push at the end)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},
{"$push": {"key": "1-value3"}})
```

else send this (set to replace the old value)

```js
update(
{"_id": {"$eq": 1}},
{"$set": {"key.$[m]": "1-value-3"}},
{"arrayFilters": [{"m": {"$eq": "1-value-2"}}]})
```

Comment: Where's the `update`...?

Comment: its ok i fixed that, it was update with pipeline, and i forgot to change the method, the problem is that i am not sure if this is what he wants, if you understand what he wants maybe try to answer i am confused, and just tried.

Comment: yeah you correctly interpreted the question. But it will take time for me to digest it. Do i have to run two different queries for this, also is there any shorter query for this.

Comment: What happened to a condition to check for `1-value-4`?    @ShubhamMaheshwari  Expand the question to explain what is going on with the candidate string that is sent to the update.

Comment: i think `1-value-4` meaning was add to index 4 meaning the end, but i wasnt sure, @ShubhamMaheshwari try to fix the question it wasn't clear, if you want this, you could say replace if member found or else add to the end of the array.

Comment: i added alternative way, without aggregation update, that you will find probably simpler.Bu t its not atomic. And its 2 queries.

Comment: in case any of you didn't understood the question i have updated it. please refer to it.

Comment: ok this answer does what you want i think, try one of those 2 ways, and i think you will be ok. if works accept it as solution also, this helps me and others to know if question has working answer.